# Получение файла настроек

Tags: php, mysql

**Пролог:**

Заранее предупрежу, что я себя отношу к разряду "Хелоуворлдщиков", так что могу выражаться неясно, неточно и неправильно и прошу делать на это скидку. :)

Итак, приступим. Для удобства обращения с БД её настройки (хост, имя и т.д.) я вынес в отдельный файл. Допустим, bd.txt, который выглядит так:

```
<?
Тут я присваиваю переменным данные
?>
```

После этого файл подключается функцией require_once к тем скриптам, которые нуждаются в подключении к БД. В итоге я получаю путь site.ua/inc/bd.txt по которому светятся все настройки для базы данных.

Вопросов будет 2:

1. Чем отличается `<? ... ?>` от `<?php ... ?>`
2. Как защитить bd.txt от посторонних глаз?

P.S. Знаю, что такой подход в корне неверный, так что прошу не бить палками.

Comment: [как защитить пароль от БД ?][1]


  [1]: http://hashcode.ru/questions/154023/php-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%BC-%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%BC-%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D1%88%D0%B5-%D1%85%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C-%D0%BE%D1%82-%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B7%D1%8B-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85

Answer (score 2):

1. <? ... ?> - устаревший короткий вариант записи. Подробнее об этом - [читайте тут](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/language.basic-syntax.phptags.php)
2. Для защиты, первое, что нужно сделать, так это забыть о том, что важные данные можно хранить в текстовом файле. И уж тем более, что это данные на подключение к БД!

Comment: \\\<? ... ?> - устаревший вариант записи
Что за бред. Совсем не устаревший.

В шаблонах, чаще всего его и используют.

Comment: я понимаю. Что мне делать? Как поступить?

Comment: @fStrange, хорошо, пусть не устаревший (хотя для меня, он таким и является), но в каких это шаблонах он чаще всего используется?

----------

@r0ocket, в php-файле что мешает?

Comment: А если откроется непосредственно этот php-файл? Делать редирект?

Comment: @r0ocket зачем redirect ? exit:

    ;<?php
    ;exit
    ;?>
    [section]
    setting1="value1";
    читаем http://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.parse-ini-file.php

Comment: я бы посоветовал никогда не использовать ini файлы, а файлы конфигурации выносить за пределы публичного доступа.

Comment: lampa это не ini файл а .php который парсится как ini, за пределы не всегда удается вынести, да и в любом случае это полумера.

Comment: можно добавить в папку и настроить в htaccess параметры доступа (Allow, Deny) или же запаролить Auth-ом...

Answer (score 0):

Ваш db.txt можно вынести за пределы видимости. Например разместить вне папки public_html или как там настроен ваш DocumentRoot. В ответ обратившись, получит forbidden

А так же в .htaccess прописать директиву:

```
AddType application/x-httpd-php .php .txt
```

В таком случае вызов по адресу site.ua/inc/bd.txt ничего не вернет.